# How to cast each element in Scala List?

Tags: scala

I have an API (from third party java library) that looks like:

```
public List<?> getByXPath(String xpathExpr)
```

defined on a class called DomNode

I want to do something like to get Scala List in which each item is of the specified type:

```
val txtNodes: List[DomText] = node.getByXPath(xpath).toList
```

But compiler gives error: type mismatch.

what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: This required `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to compile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to cast each element of the list, to prove all of them have the required type.
You can do that just when iterating, for instance

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).map{case d: DomText => d}.toList
```

or

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).map(_.asInstanceOf[DomText]).toList
```

whichever writing of the cast suits you better.

You could also cast the list, `node.getByXPath(xPath).toList.asInstanceOf[List[DomText]]`, but you would get a warning, as this cast is done without any check because of type erasure (just as in java).

Comment: I believe your two examples above will give different behavior for lists that have elements other than a DomText in them, with the first example silently dropping them and the second example throwing a runtime exception.  If so, the choice between them would involve more than personal preference.

Comment: They do not. map takes a Function argument, not a PartialFunction, and it will fail if the function fails. collect as presented in the @Alois Cochard answer will filter. My two variants differ however in the exception they throw, MatchError with pattern matching, ClassCastException with asInstanceOf.

Answer (score 11):

Since Scala 2.8, you can use 'collect':

```
scala> "hi" :: 1 :: "world" :: 4 :: Nil collect {case s:String => s}
res13: List[String] = List(hi, world)
```

Source:
http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/filter-with-flatmap-or-collect.html

Comment: Nice and I keep forgetting this one. However there is a difference. As demonstraged by your example, collect will filter out the elements which cannot be casted. On the other hand, map will fail if there is such an element. In the present case where all the cast are ok, it does not matters. When one is not sure the cast will be ok, one has to decide whether filtering of failure is wanted.

Comment: @didierd You are totally correct, and there is a nice example in the comments of the blog post I mentioned showing how to handle cast exception in a idiomatic way !